# Error with installing pyinstaller with pip

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm new to python, and I want to create an application with pyinstaller (I saw on websites that it is used to make an application with python scripts/source files), so when I try to install pyinstaller with "pip install pyinstaller" it comes up with the following error:

````
Collecting pyinstaller
Using cached pyinstaller-5.3-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-unpack-en9t4rq5\\pyinstaller-5.3-py3-none-win_amd64.whl'```

I'm not sure why this keeps happening if anyone knows a fix to this, please suggest it!!
(I have the latest version of pip (22.2.2).)
[error when installing pyinstaller][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtF9I.png
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing pyinstaller gives an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343455/installing-pyinstaller-gives-an-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reinstall python, install the latest version from here :-

https://www.python.org/downloads/

while installing python make sure to check the box 'ADD PYTHON TO PATH' in the installation directory

after that open CMD and type `python` if it doesn't show any error you are good to go.

now reopen CMD and type `python -m pip install -–upgrade pip`

now install your preferred library : `pip install pyinstaller`